# Persistence entities not serializable

Tags: java, jpa, serialization, jms

I am getting following error:

```
SEVERE: null
javax.jms.MessageFormatException: [C4017]: Invalid message format.
at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.MapMessageImpl.checkValidObjectType(MapMessageImpl.java:653)
at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.MapMessageImpl.setObject(MapMessageImpl.java:632)
at buyer.Main.sendCart(Main.java:287)
```

after I try to send Persistence object through MapMessage in JMS system. And I am not quite sure why it happens since MapMessage accepts only serializable objects for value, and Persistence entities are serializable. I would appreciate any help! My Java code is following.

```
package entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "carts")
@NamedQuery(
    name = "carts.findAll",
    query = "select c from Cart c"
)
public class Cart implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "buyer_id")
private Long buyerId;

@Column(name = "card_id")
private Long cardId;

@Column(name = "successful")
private boolean successful;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "buyer_id")
private Buyer buyer;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "card_id")
private Card card;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart", cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<CartItem> cartItems;

public Cart() {
}

public Cart(Long buyerId, Long cardId, boolean successful) {
    this.buyerId = buyerId;
    this.cardId = cardId;
    this.successful = successful;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Long getBuyerId() {
    return buyerId;
}

public void setBuyerId(Long buyerId) {
    this.buyerId = buyerId;
}

public Long getCardId() {
    return cardId;
}

public void setCardId(Long cardId) {
    this.cardId = cardId;
}

public boolean isSuccessful() {
    return successful;
}

public void setSuccessful(boolean successful) {
    this.successful = successful;
}

public Buyer getBuyer() {
    return buyer;
}

public void setBuyer(Buyer buyer) {
    this.buyer = buyer;
}

public Card getCard() {
    return card;
}

public void setCard(Card card) {
    this.card = card;
}

public List<CartItem> getCartItems() {
    return cartItems;
}

public void setCartItems(List<CartItem> cartItems) {
    this.cartItems = cartItems;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 53 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);
    hash = 53 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.buyerId);
    hash = 53 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.cardId);
    hash = 53 * hash + (this.successful ? 1 : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Cart other = (Cart) obj;
    if (this.successful != other.successful) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.buyerId, other.buyerId)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.cardId, other.cardId)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Cart{" + "id=" + id + ", buyerId=" + buyerId + ", cardId=" + cardId + ", successful=" + successful + '}';
}
}
```

Relevant method that sends message.

```
private static Buyer sendCart(Cart cart, String tempId, Buyer buyer) {
    JMSContext context = connectionFactory.createContext(2);

    try {
        Destination queue = context.createQueue("mediator");
        JMSProducer producer = context.createProducer();

        MapMessage message = context.createMapMessage();

        message.setObject("data", cart);
        message.setObject("tempid", tempId);
        message.setObject("type", MessageType.BUYER_SENDING_CART);

        producer.send(queue, message);

    } catch (JMSException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just want to mention that error is occurring on `message.setObject("data", cart);` line.

Comment: MapMessage can only (compiletime) check, that the object that' s the parameter is serializeable. However, if there are related Objects that are not serializeable that will fail at runtime... Are Card, Buyer, CartItem (and their related classes) serializeable to? Also, is the used implementation of List serializeable? Would start checking that ...

Comment: They are all Persistence entities, so they are all serializable...

Comment: Then Serialization shouldn't be a Problem ... seems like C0417 could be something else too... "Cause The client runtime encountered an error when processing a JMS Message; for example, during data type conversion." I'd try to get more Logoutput from MapMessage ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is the MapMessage. According to [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MapMessage.html):

> A MapMessage object is used to send a set of name-value pairs. The
>   names are String objects, and the values are primitive data types in
>   the Java programming language. The names must have a value that is not
>   null, and not an empty string. The entries can be accessed
>   sequentially or randomly by name. The order of the entries is
>   undefined. MapMessage inherits from the Message interface and adds a
>   message body that contains a Map.

And:

> They may also be read or written generically as objects.

So even if MapMessage offers an "setObject" Method, the parameter used must be a primitive Type.

To pass non-primitive Types use [ObjectMessage](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/ObjectMessage.html)

Comment: I need to use MapMessage because it has acknowledgeThisMessage() method, ObjectMessage only has acknowledge() method that acknowledges all messages and one part of my system depends on acknowledgeThisMessage() method because I need to acknowledge only the current message. If there is some alternative to it, I would gladly change it all to ObjectMessage. Do you know about some alternative? Some way to acknowledge only the last received message with ObjectMessage?

Comment: Hmm are you sure acknowledgeThisMessage doesn't work on ObjectMessage? Seems like you have to cast anyway to get that Method ( `((com.sun.messaging.jms.Message)message).acknowledgeThisMessage();`), should work on ObjectMessage too? (At least _The com.sun.messaging.jms.Message interface defines enhanced capabilities of a JMS Message in Sun Java System Message Queue._ from the JavaDoc would suggest that)

Comment: Thank you so much, I have started modifying the system and soon I will know the result, but all looks good for now!

Comment: It did! You are awesome!